# Apple TV Pairing With Xcode 12

Tags: xcode, tvos

Im trying to pair my Xcode(12.2) with My Apple TV 4K. The Apple TV is visible in the device and simulators window. After clicking "Pair With Apple TV" the TV shows 6 digit code and after entering it, my Macbook is shown in Apple TV's "Remote App and Devices" window. But my Xcode is unable to detect my Apple TV and my device and simulator Window looks like this. Anybody here facing the same issue ? Please Advice. TIA [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOJXr.png)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I've just repeated clicking "Pair With Apple TV" and it helped.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue on M1 MBP for Apple TV 4k 2021 version.

my record shows how to repeat this issue: https://youtu.be/hKM1t7MRfx4